# How to set required validation for inner field of repeater in OctoberCMS?

Tags: validation, octobercms

[image: form_image]

I have tried below code but it's not working for me.

**fields.yaml**

```
fields:
    repetor_name:
        label: Repeater
        prompt: 'Add new item'
        span: auto
        type: repeater
        required: 1
        form:
            fields:
                required_text:
                    label: Text
                    span: auto
                    required: 1
                    type: text
```

**Model**

```
   public $rules = [
   'repetor_name' => 'required',
   'required_text' =>'required'
    ];
```

Please Share your knowledge with me if anyone has the solution for it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `beforeValidate()` function and looping through the repeater, there is much more convenient way how to accomplish it - by using wildcard in the rules section:

```
public $rules = [
   'repetor_name' => 'required',
   'repetor_name.*.required_text' =>'required'
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add Below code in **model file**

```
 public $rules = [
       'repetor_name' => 'required', //repeater field is required
      // 'required_text' =>'required' You have to remove this line
        ];  



/* We have to create custom function in model to validate inner fields of  repeater*/


public function beforeValidate()
        {
         foreach ($this->repetor_name as $key => $value) {
         $this->rules['repetor_name.'.$key.'.required_text'] = 'required';
         }
```